# In this circuit what is the function of this resistance in parallel with a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, resistors

[image]

I understand that the capacitor produces a resistance proportional to the 50 Hz of the mains input current, in this case 220 volts

But why is that resistance installed in parallel, what function does the resistance have?

Thanks

Comment: That resistor wouldn't be a 0603 sized SMD part.  That size part can't handle the voltage, and the terminals would be too close together for that voltage.

Comment: If you build that thing, do not touch any part of it while it is plugged in.  Safest is to close it up in a box so it can't bite you.

Comment: that resistor marked 0603 is mysterious,  resistor numbers don't start with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely a high value resistor to discharge the capacitor when the circuit is disconnected from the mains AC supply. This is purely for safety and not functionally required for the circuit.

Comment: Thank you..., I had not thought of it

Comment: It may be similar to a 'bleeder' resistor. It is used for safety purposes.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted (check mark) if it is satisfactory to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is transformerless power supply. Capacitor restrict current flowing. Resistor for discharging capacitor then main power is off for safety purpose. Also the circuit not complete. If main power on in peak of sinusoid, discharged capacitor make short circuit, current limited only by ESR of capacitor. Resistor in series should be added.

Comment: Thanks for the information